# Difficulty getting barycentric_rational from c++ boost library to work how I need it to

Tags: c++, boost, interpolation

I am using barycentric_rational from the C++ Boost library to interpolate on data stored in vectors. The vectors are populated inside a class, and I need the interpolation to be performed after the vectors have been populated, so I can write an access function to get the interpolated value at a specific point. Something like this:

```
class V{
public:
    V(/* some arguments */){

        //populate x and y

        b=barycentric_rational<double>(x.data(),y.data(),x.size());
    }

    double psi(double r){
         return b(r);
    }

private:
   std::vector<double> x,y;
   barycentric_rational<double> b;  
};
```

I get the error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to    ‘boost::math::barycentric_rational<double>::barycentric_rational()
```

I think I get this message because b needs to be initialized in an initialiser list, but the code to populate x and y in my application is complicated. Setting x and y in a separate public method doesn't work for the same reason.

I have tried the following solution:

```
class V{
public:
    V(/* some arguments */):b(nullptr){

        //populate x and y

        b=new barycentric_rational<double>(x.data(),y.data(),x.size());
    }

    ~V(){
          delete b;
     }

    double psi(double r){
         return b->operator()(r);
    }

private:
   std::vector<double> x,y;
   barycentric_rational<double> *b; 
};
```

which seems to work. However, I don't like it for two reasons: a) I am using raw pointers, and eventually I need to be able to use copy and assignment operators which will get me into trouble, and b) I am sure there must be a neater way of doing this.

Please can someone suggest a way of doing what I need?

Comment: It seems Boost has no `barycentric_rational<sometype>()` constructor, so you can't have `barycentric_rational<double> b;`. Anyhow, why should you have it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just init it in initialization list. If you need to use some special logic to populate x and y, you can do it in separate method.

```
class V{
public:
    V(/* some arguments */)
    : x(populateX()),  y(populateY()), b(x.data(),y.data(),x.size())
    {
    }

    std::vector<double> populateX() {
    }
    std::vector<double> populateY() {
    }

    double psi(double r){
         return b(r);
    }

private:
   std::vector<double> x,y;
   barycentric_rational<double> b;  
};
```

If the code that populates x and y is too complecated, and initialization of x and y can not be done separately then you can move it to separate class:

```
struct XY {
    XY(/* some args */) {
        //init x and y
    }
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;
};
class V{
public:
    V(/* some arguments */)
    : xy(/*some args */), b(xy.x.data(),xy.y.data(),xy.x.size())
    {
    }

    double psi(double r){
         return b(r);
    }

private:
   XY xy;
   barycentric_rational<double> b;  
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this might work. It did not occur to me that you could call class methods in the initiliser list. I shall try this.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is just to initialize b with empty x and y, and then assign to it another correct value:

```
V(/* some arguments */) : b(x.data(),y.data(),x.size()){
    //populate x and y
    b=barycentric_rational<double>(x.data(),y.data(),x.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try this, but it caused barycentric_rational to complain that the data length cannot be (strictly) less than the interpolation order, which is an optional argument in barycentric_rational.

Comment: This solution still works: Initialize it with phony data of the required length, then reassign it. Seems, however, that this is a design flaw, and you can work around it.